# Compatibility of musixtex with amsmath

Tags: amsmath, musixtex

I've been using `musixtex` and `amsmath` in the same document (article class) up until I today encountered the problem that whenever I type `\cup` for a set union, a quaver appears instead (or sometimes compiling just reports an error). I am not within the environment called by `\begin{music}` when this occurs. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

To give an example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} %Maths stuff
\usepackage{amsthm} %Theorems
\usepackage{amsfonts}  % for blackboard bold, etc
\usepackage{musixtex}

\begin{document}
$A\cup B$
\end{document}
```

Comment: welcome to tex.xs.  please provide a small example that will compile and show the problem, so that others can experiment.

Comment: Oh - sorry, I've added an example now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`musixtex` overrides the latex `\cup` command, but you could do the following to use one or other definition, depending on whether you are in math.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} %Maths stuff
\usepackage{amsthm} %Theorems
\usepackage{amsfonts}  % for blackboard bold, etc
\let\cupA\cup
\usepackage{musixtex}
\let\cupB\cup

\protected\def\cup{\ifmmode\expandafter\cupA\else\expandafter\cupB\fi}

\begin{document}

1: $A\cup B$

2: A \cup B

\end{document}
```

Comment: actually, `\cup` for math isn't defined by `amsmath` -- it's a symbol name command carried over from plain tex.  anyhow, this is a good approach when such symbol names are re-used and their context can be separated by whether it's within math or not.